GoB and color attribute problems
I have a model imported from zbrush to blender using GoB, the model is uvd and all color textures show up as color attributes.
Since I used a skin material in Zbrush, the head was imported with just the texture from paint without the base material, so it's a white head with no base material or color, just the polypaint I did on it with a white background without the base color of the Zbrush matcap.
I've edited the exported texture to fill the white with skin color but it's still shows white in Blender, it's like the color attribute has nothing to do with the actual exported map.
I'm new to blender and I've tried adding a color index or the texture as a uv map and I get broken results, I tried tint, subsurface scattering and mixing it with a base color and it still has a white base.
I've watched several videos on materials and colors, searched for a solution on forums for days and still haven't found how to solve this.  I'm using blender 4.1

“Color index…” Do you mean vertex color? Also, one cannot use an image texture as a UV map. IDK what you did, but it wasn’t that. A UV map defines how any 2D texture is mapped to the 3D object.

Not color index or vertex color. Color attribute according to the name of the node.  I import each part using GoB which is a script that exports from zbrush to blender. I don't think it's using maps, although all parts have uvs and when I get them to blender,  they have texture, displacement and normal map nodes. I also deleted a bunch of exported ztl files in a hidden folder and now all color information is gone. I think I might have to get rid of GoB and save in zbrush each part and import them into blender manually and see what happens.
